# Angular ensure operation takes at least N ms to complete

Tags: angularjs

I have a save function that works so fast it almost looks unbelievable, I'd like to artificially increase the time it takes if was too quick to complete to make it "feel" better.

Currently I have a service that is used to save back a schedule, how can I detect and wait N ms if it was too quick?

```
addScheduleServices.factory('addScheduleAPIservice', function ($http) {
    var addScheduleAPI = {};

    // this is often too quick
    addScheduleAPI.save = function (schedule) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: schedule,
            url: '/settings/addschedule'
        });
    }

    return addScheduleAPI;
});

// Use within controller
addScheduleAPIservice.save($scope.schedule)
    .success(function () {
        //success state
    })
    .error(function () {
        // error state
    });
```

Comment: I would strongly advice against spending time worrying about it. It's 2014, people expect trivial things like saving data to happen instantly.

Comment: My main worry is that I put a semi opaque model over the form which flashes.  Surely worrying about user interface design is a good thing? :)

Comment: IMHO you're approaching the problem the wrong way. Wait N ms, if the request hasn't finished yet *then* show the "loading" overlay. Best of both worlds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could introduce $q and $timeout. $q allows you to wait for multiple promises to resolve. Using this you could implement a minimum duration:

```
addScheduleServices.factory('addScheduleAPIservice', function ($http, $q, $timeout) {
    var addScheduleAPI = {};

    // this is often too quick
    addScheduleAPI.save = function (schedule) {
        var addSchedule = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: schedule,
            url: '/settings/addschedule'
        });
        var wait = $timeout(function() {
        }, 3000, false);
        return $q.all([addSchedule, wait]).then(function(p1) {
             // success
             return p1;
        });
     }

    return addScheduleAPI;
});
```

Comment: How Do I pass schedule into `addSchedule` can I just do `[addSchedule(schedule), wait]`

Comment: The example doesnt quite work, its moaning saying `schedule` is undefined within `addSchedule` (new code)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I had just arrived at this solution myself but the `addScheduleAPIservice.save($scope.schedule).success(function () {` in the calling function throws `undefined is not a function` now, are we still returning a promise?

Comment: Moved the addSchedule definition inside the save block - should work now.

Comment: Hey, I have done this, in fact Ive copied your exmaple and added the correct dependencies but still get `undefined is not a function` when calling `.success()` on `addScheduleAPI` as per my previous comment

Comment: You are calling it like this? addScheduleAPIservice.save(schedule).then(function() {})?

Comment: I was using `.success`.. Using .then works correctly!

Comment: .success is not formally part of the Promise API as it does not allow you to chain successive promises together. then(success,fail), however, does.  You should be using .then().

Comment: Thanks thats very informative.  Just out of interest if one of the promises fail will the `then` still be called?

Comment: Yes, but it will be the failure callback.